# I am not able to get the size of the arraylist on creation of the activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

I am a real beginner with Android and I have been trying to make a simple quiz app using Firebase but when I want to get the size of the ArrayList which contains the questions, the size of the array list is zero on the creation of the activity but when I restart the quiz from the alert dialog box everything works fine. I am not able to find out what the problem is. Any suggestion would be really helpful

This is my code

```
TextView totalquestions,question;
    Button ansa,ansb,ansc,ansd,submit;

    int score=0;

    int currentquestionindex=0;
    String selectedanswer="";
    private final List<Questionlist> questionlists= new ArrayList<>();
    int tq;
    int testno=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_python);
        Swipetorefresh();


        totalquestions=findViewById(R.id.totalquestions3_python);
        question=findViewById(R.id.python_q);
        ansa=findViewById(R.id.py_ansa);
        ansb=findViewById(R.id.py_ansb);
        ansc=findViewById(R.id.py_ansc);
        ansd=findViewById(R.id.py_ansd);
        submit=findViewById(R.id.py_submit);

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Python.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        progressDialog.show();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child("Python").getChildren()){
                    String questions=dataSnapshot.child("question").getValue(String.class);
                    String getansa = dataSnapshot.child("option1").getValue(String.class);
                    String getansb = dataSnapshot.child("option2").getValue(String.class);
                    String getansc = dataSnapshot.child("option3").getValue(String.class);
                    String getansd = dataSnapshot.child("option4").getValue(String.class);
                    String getans = dataSnapshot.child("answer").getValue(String.class);



                    Questionlist questionlist = new Questionlist(questions,getansa,getansb,getansc,getansd,getans);
                    questionlists.add(questionlist);

                }

                progressDialog.hide();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        ansa.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansb.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansc.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansd.setOnClickListener(this);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
 loadnewquestion();


    }

   private void loadnewquestion() {
       tq=questionlists.size();

       totalquestions.setText("Total Questions: "+tq);

        if(currentquestionindex == tq){
            
            finishquiz();
            return;

        }

        question.setText(questionlists.get(currentquestionindex).getQuestion());
        ansa.setText(questionlists.get(currentquestionindex).getOption1());
       ansb.setText(questionlists.get(currentquestionindex).getOption2());
       ansc.setText(questionlists.get(currentquestionindex).getOption3());
       ansd.setText(questionlists.get(currentquestionindex).getOption4());


      
    }
 private void finishquiz() {
       
        String passstatus="";
        if(score>tq*0.60){
            passstatus="passed";
        }
        else{
            passstatus="failed";
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(passstatus)
                .setMessage("score is "+ score+" out of "+tq)
                .setPositiveButton("restart",((dialogInterface, i) -> restartquiz()))
                .setNegativeButton("go back",((dialogInterface, i) -> goback()))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();
    }

    private void goback() {
        startActivity(new Intent(Python.this,daily_quiz.class));
    }

    private void restartquiz() {
        score=0;
        currentquestionindex=0;
        loadnewquestion();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ansa.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.button_qa));
        ansb.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.button_qa));
        ansc.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.button_qa));
        ansd.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.button_qa));

        Button clickedbutton = (Button) view;
        if (clickedbutton.getId() == R.id.py_submit) {




                String getanswer = questionlists.get(currentquestionindex).getAnswer();
                if (selectedanswer.equals(getanswer)) {
                    score++;

                }
                currentquestionindex++;
                loadnewquestion();

        }

             else {
                    selectedanswer = clickedbutton.getText().toString();
                    clickedbutton.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_ans));
                }
            }
}
```

This is the image of my database:

[image]

I tried it the static way by just writing the questions in another java class and then calling it in the main class, this way the size of the array is found on the creation of the activity but when I call it from the database it is creating problems.

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you understand Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase Realtime Database asynchronous. So there is no way you can calculate the size of the `questionlists` before the data is loaded completely. The solution is always the same. Any code that needs to use data that comes from a Realtime Database, needs to be inside the `onDataChange()` method or be called from there.

So in your particular case, you should call the `loadnewquestion()` method from within the `onDataChange()`, in order to see the size of the list. To solve this, please move the following line of code:

```
loadnewquestion();
```

Before:

```
progressDialog.hide();
```

One more thing, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add:

```
Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
```

Inside the `onCancelled()`. If you don't and your request fails, you'll never know why.

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped. Thanks for not just giving the solution but also explaining it.